# Correct Isolation Level for Frequently Called Update SP?

Tags: sql-server, isolation-level

Let's say I have a single table that tracks stock prices (an easily relatable example for this problem).  I track 1000 tickers, and have a process that is constantly receiving market data and making updates to the table via a stored procedure.

I am not concerned about collision between updates that happen for the same ticker.  Let's assume for whatever reason I am fine with two updates to the same ticker being applied out of order (this won't happen in my scenario).  I would like the stored procedure to have as little contention as possible.

In the current scenario, the proc is getting called many time simultaneously and it is timing out.

The proc is currently using REPEATABLE READ as an isolation level.  I did not write the proc, so am unsure as to why this was chosen.

My questions:

1. It it possible that using REPEATABLE READ is (indirectly) causing these timeouts?
2. Would READ UNCOMMITTED be a better choice based on my criteria above?

Answer (score 2):

As the isolation levels increase, concurrency tumbles. The higher the isolation, the lower the concurrency. Using high concurrency levels like REPEATABLE READ or SERIALIZABLE will cause contention, blockage and poor concurrency.

Except `SNAPSHOT`. Snapshot, aka. row versioning, is different. With snapshot ON readers never block behind writers. It is usually a very good match for workloads that are read intensively and write at the same time. It has a cost, but I would strongly urge you to start by investigating the performance with SNAPSHOT enabled first:

- [Understanding Row Versioning-Based Isolation Levels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189050.aspx)
- [Row Versioning Resource Usage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175492.aspx)
- [Enabling Row Versioning-Based Isolation Levels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175095.aspx)

Note that isolation level has to be set also by your **readers**.

Comment: Interesting, and I will read up this.  Would READ UNCOMMITTED be the next best choice, since it is the next lowest isolation level?

Comment: [READ UNCOMMITTED is inconsistent](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlcat/archive/2007/02/01/previously-committed-rows-might-be-missed-if-nolock-hint-is-used.aspx)